# Operations links missing from Content list

Tags: 7, users

I've just inherited a project with the odd issue of all Operations links being empty, whether when viewing records in a content list, or viewing themes. Here's what I'm seeing:

[image: missing links]

This problem exists no matter what theme is selected for admins, and I am logged in as an administrator. Any ideas where I can hunt down the problem?

Comment: Try to clear the cache.

Comment: Done, no change.